# Does it make sense to copy Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord object to some matrix/array/table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm writing some easy app for students for learning English words. I get the phrases list from the DB

```
phrases = Phrase.all
```

Now every kid should be able to add few his own custom phrases to the lesson. But, I can't do:

```
phrases.phrase = params["new_phrase"]
phrases.phrase_translation = params["new_phrase_translation"]
phrases.save
```

because it will extend the set of vocabulary for all students. I want custom phrases to be isolated for every single person. Additionally I try to reduce DB impact. I don't need to create separate tables with custom vocabulary, but only store them in the memory for the current session.

The decision is to copy 'phrases' into some structure that I will be using only for one separate session and it will be destroyed once someone finishes using the app.

```
Custom_phrase = Struct.new(:new_phrase, :new_phrase_translation)
Custom_phrase.new('xxx', 'yyy')
```

Please let me know if my approach makes sense and how to copy 'phrases' to this new structure without simple iteration. I don't think below way will work:

```
Custom_phrase = phrases.dup
```

My last idea was to store custom vocabulary in some local json file. Any thoughts about that?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make sense

No. A lot of complexity for little to no benefit.

I'd store everything in the same table `phrases`. Isolation of custom phrases can easily be done like this:

- Add column `user_id` to phrases.
- When user saves custom phrase, you set phrase's user_id to the id of the user (naturally)
- Consider phrases with `user_id=nil` to be common/shared phrases.

You can load all phrases for a user like this, for example:

```
phrases = Phrase.where(user_id: [nil, current_user.id]) 
# generates a query like this:
#   select * from phrases where user_id is null or user_id = 1234
```

Comment: Thx Sergio. This is the simples and good solution. But I want to avoid going in that direction, because the app should fullfill the Progressive Web App philosophy. So there is many reasons I want to limit the DB actions. Next is the ability students use the vocabulary with the limited Internet connection. I just simplified the case to make it more clear. Anyway the solution you provided makes sens - I'm just looking if there is any alternative way which limits DB impact to minimum.

Comment: @MickLasocki: yep, you can cache phrases in browser's local db (or something like that). I suggest you implement this one first, it's quick and reliable. And then you can experiment with making your app more "progressive". Baby steps.

Comment: @MickLasocki: also I'm quite confident that you greatly overestimate DB impact. Queries with proper index support perform very well.